# Conditional compiler directive based on platform or endianness?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c-preprocessor, endianness

I have some code that will one day find itself buried inside a large C# application, long forgotten and overlooked and me maybe long gone or senile. This code has a serious gotcha though. It is dependent on the endianness of the platform and due to the nature of the code I can't simply enclose it in `if(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)`. *(It involves some LayoutKind.Explicit structs and overlapping fields that receive outside values - the overlapping fields need to be positioned correctly for little/big endianness or the program will slowly corrupt itself as bad values are read)*

What I want is a compiler directive in the source code to either provide both struct layouts depending on the target platform ('Any CPU' is a bit of an issue) or perhaps more likely just detect if the code is being compiled for a platform other then x86 or x64 and issue a compiler `#error` so that whoever is maintaining the code gets directed to that source file and sees my comments indicating the platform dependency and whatever change is needed for big-endian.

I could stick a symbol in the build configuration, but there isn't a good way to document why it's there or otherwise ensure that it future programmers won't drop it, or blindly copy it to a new build configuration for an ARM or other big endian platform.

Comment: There is no way to refactor to use `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`? That would be the cleanest and probably most correct way to do things.

Comment: I feel your pain, but AFAIK nothing exists to directly support this

Comment: I have thought of sticking a static class/constructor in that just checks endianness and then throws a big ugly "this code won't work as compiled" exception as soon as the app is run.

Comment: Like a hard-coded unit test in a static class? Should at least be a good warning. I was going to suggest, if you can't clean up your structs, then go the other way... define each byte. i.e. make a specification that effectively maps what each byte, bit-range is. Fugly, but no endianness... downside you need a wrapper class to access.

Comment: Out of interest, why can't you unpack these structures into something cleaner. Performance? Memory?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that would work?:

```
interface MyStruct { ... }
struct BigEndianStruct : MyStruct { ... }
struct LittleEndianStruct : MyStruct { ... }
```

using MyStruct everywhere instead of the endian specific struct. To Create those structs you would have something like this:

```
public static MyStruct CreateStruct() { 
  return BitConverter.IsLittleEndian
          ? new LittleEndianStruct()
          : new BigEndianStruct();
}
```